# How do I target ES6 using TypeScript to get Async/Await support with ionic2?

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-code, ionic2

Using the default ionic2 project I updated the tsconfig.json to target "es6" and immediately started getting the following errors:

```
TypeScript error: c:/test/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(17,14): Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
TypeScript error: typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(3,14): Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
```

How do I properly target es6 to avoid these build errors?

Comment: You may need to `exclude` some `.d.ts` file or otherwise futz with your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting es6, you won't need es6-shim, if I'm not mistaken. Remove it from your typings.json, delete the typings folder and reinstall. That should take care of the duplicate identifier.